# How to add manually created sitemap.xml, Parcel JS and Netlify

Tags: javascript, bundler, netlify, sitemap, parceljs

I have a simple Javascript HTML website. I used Parcel JS for bundling and Netlify to deploy the website.

Now, I want to add **sitemap.xml** file manually to my project. I tried creating the file using some online tools and then added it to my project and deployed it. But it seems that it wasn't working. When I tried [www.website.com/sitemap.xml](http://www.website.com/sitemap.xml) Netlify says PAGE NOT FOUND.

On which level should I add my sitemap.xml file? I see that after adding sitemap.xml to the top level of the project the bundler is not including this file. Do I need to make any configuration to Parcel JS to include the sitemap.xml?

Do I also configure anything in netlify ?

[image]